# Adding values dynamically to a MultiSelect in DOJO

Tags: dojo, addition, multi-select, dropdownbox

I am having a MultiSelect dropdown in DOJO. Now the user should be able to add/delete values to/from the MultiSelect dynamically. Any examples/code snippets on how to achieve this in dojo. Am completely new to dojo..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

An example of operations with `DOJO MultiSelect` can be found here
http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.9.1/dojo-release-1.9.1/dijit/tests/form/test_MultiSelect.html

Documentation at the following link:

http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dijit/form/MultiSelect

Comment: Sharing documentation is not an answer.